# Phpmailer with Aamazon SES sending email work on local server but not work on web server

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, phpmailer

I have develop one application with help of php. I want to integrate Amazon SES Email service for sending email to user when they regiseter on over website. I've tested this on my localhost, it send email with Amazon SES without any issues. But when i publish to my remote web server, it sends error like this:

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 
>       The following From address failed: info@abc.com

I'm using Godaddy email hosting.

This is my simple code

```
<?php
function Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body)
{
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$from = "info@abc.com";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(true); // SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // SMTP authentication
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host       = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->Username   = "xxx";  // SES SMTP  username
$mail->Password   = "xxx";  // SES SMTP password
$mail->SetFrom($from, 'From Name');
$mail->AddReplyTo($from,'test');
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = $to;
$mail->AddAddress($address, $to);

if(!$mail->Send())
 echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
 echo 'Mail Send';
}

?>
```

Comment: Who is your web host? Are you sure they don't block outgoing email traffic?

Comment: my web host is godaddy.

Comment: Search before you post. There are many questions describing exactly that GoDaddy blocks outbound SMTP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP connection works from local machine but not from GoDaddy hosting. Same smtp server used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096065/smtp-connection-works-from-local-machine-but-not-from-godaddy-hosting-same-smtp)